# ASp.net MVC Long running controller task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Controller action takes long time to run (expected). In the below code ,

```
ProcessImportFileAPI(HoldAPI)
```

timesout after 1 hour.

```
public JsonResult DataFileUpload(string positionDate)
        {
            // Reset validation error collection
            ImportDataValidationErrors = new List<ImportFileRecord>();
            string[] errs;
            try
            {
                var HoldAPI = "SomeAPI" 
                retDictAPI = ProcessImportFileAPI(HoldAPI);
                string ReturnVal = "Import is successful";
                return Json(ReturnVal); //never return because of TIMEOUT.

            }
```

Controller action is performing all taks correctly, but I am unable to return value back to view because of timeout. How can I solve this? any pointers?

Comment: SO I assume `HoldAPI` didn't return any result. Is it third-party API or it written by you? Also it's interesting what code is inside `ProcessImportFileAPI` method

Comment: ProcessImportFileAPI(HoldAPI) takes in the HoldAPI and it takes >1 hour to finish (fetch market data, update records, etc). This expected. when I debug, my codes comes until return Json(ReturnVal); but then view gets nothing back.

Comment: If you really are running something which is expected to take 1 hour then you need to offload that to some sort of queuing system. (To be run async.)

Comment: Async did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used async controller to solve my issue.